# Firebase crash reporting bitcode support upload symbol files

Tags: firebase-crash-reporting

I'm having trouble uploading the symbol files for my app to Firebase. I have tried to follow the instruction in the Firebase documentation but without success.

When I run the following in the terminal

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload -i "/Users/***/Dropbox/Answer\ This/Answer\ This/Info.plist" -p "/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist" "/Users/***/Dropbox/answer-this-3f26b-firebase-crashreporting-gqqd6-*NOT-CORRECT-NUMERS*.json" "FF8C3C56-0498-3C5C-B3C7-56B96A620001"
```

where the UUID is the one given for that particular crash in Firebase. I get this result:

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload: line 122: FCR_PROD_VERS: environment variable empty or unset

Explicitly add to environment or set GoogleService-Info.plist (-p)
and Info.plist (-i) flags to extract values from the files.

Try "./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload -h" for details.
```

Comment: Did you try "./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload -h" as suggested?

Comment: Yes with no help

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps carefully**

1. Add your unzipped dsym folder to your project's main directory
2. Add this script to the dsym folder
3. Open terminal
4. cd into the dsym folder in the project's main directory
5. Run this python script i.e 'python batch_upload_files.py'

https://github.com/hanijazzar/Contributions/blob/master/batch_upload_files.py